# Qt Camera error "failed to set flash mode"

Tags: qt, qt-mobility

I've been tryin to make a prog to set flash on. I managed to run it on a Nokia C7 with out any compilation errors, but when I click the push button to set flash on I get the following error:

> [Qt Message] Camera error: "Failed to set flash mode."

The code I've used is:

```
QCamera *camera = new QCamera;
QCameraExposure *cameraexpo = camera->exposure();
cameraexpo->setFlashMode(QCameraExposure::FlashOn);
```

I use Qt 4.7.4 with Qt Creator 2.2.0.

Answer (score 2):

Try checking

```
bool bIsSupported = cameraexpo->isFlashModeSupported(QCameraExposure::FlashOn);
bool bIsReady = cameraexpo->isFlashReady();
```

and display their results somewhere